# Generate new XML from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I currently have this working code:
(tvdata.xslt)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/tv_guide">
            <tv>
                <xsl:for-each select="document('cmore.xml')/tv/programme">
                    <programme>
                            <title>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                            </title>
                            <xsl:for-each select="category">
                                <category>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                                </category>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                    </programme>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tv>
     </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(tv-guide.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tvdata.xslt"?>
<tv_guide>
</tv_guide>
```

Where cmore.xml is an XML-file from http://xmltv.xmltv.se. What I want to do is to generate a new XML file with the data in the XSLT-file with tv_guide as the root. I've tried using result-document but it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a minor modification, your XSLT file will work well. I added a variable to designate the file name of the program input data as well as the program output data. So the XSLT could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="curFile" select="'first.cmore.dk_2018-10-10.xml'" />
    <xsl:variable name="outFile" select="'cmore.out.xml'" />

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="{$outFile}" method="xml">
            <tv>
                <xsl:for-each select="document($curFile)/tv/programme">
                    <programme>
                            <title>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                            </title>
                            <xsl:for-each select="category">
                                <category>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                                </category>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                    </programme>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tv>
        </xsl:result-document>
     </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output file is designated by the `outFile` variable. If you want to change this to an input parameter, change this line to `<xsl:param name="outFile" />` and pass the parameter as input parameter to the stylesheet.

For this to work, you have to remove the DTD definition line from the `XML` file (I didn't find it) or add the DTD-file to the working directory (If you know where it can be obtained).

However, this way you can probably transform all the XML files from the given link.

If you want to provide the name of the XML file dynamically, change the `xsl:variable` to an `xsl:param` and pass the appropriate parameter to the XSLT processor.

Comment: this gives me the same result as before. I wanted to know if there's a way I can use for example xsl:result-doucment to generate a new xml-file

Comment: @M.H: I changed my answer to incorporate your suggestion. The output is as you want.